# Navbar more on the right side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a hoverable side navigation bar that appears on the right-hand side. The issue I am facing is that the navigation bar does not go as far as I want it to. I want the navigation bar to touch the side of the browser page to the point where only a little bit of the navigation bar shows. Can someone help me fix this? Thank you.

[This is the link to W3S to show you where I got the code from](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_buttons)

To be more specific as to where the navigation bar should be I have circled the place where I want it to be:

[image]

This is how I want the navigation bar to show:

[image]

This is how it is supposed to look like on hover:

[image]

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family:'Montserrat';
}

.polymorph{    
  fill:#EDE1DB;
    }

#showdashboard, #goback{
    position:absolute;
    margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:30%;
    background:none;
    border: 1px solid #163C68;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#163C68;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:0;
}

#gobutton{
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #AAC0AA;
}

#blip{
    position:fixed;
    color:#298BE2;
    right:25%;
    top:0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translateY(-800px);
}

#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  right: -80px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #163C68;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  right: 0;
}

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #EDE1DB;
}

#blog {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #EDE1DB;
}

#projects {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #EDE1DB;
}

#contact {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #EDE1DB
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Meter Dashboard Animation">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="LandingPage.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <button id="showdashboard">Show Meter Dashboard</button>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 237.5 104.8" >
            <polygon class="polymorph" points="237.5,104.8 0,104.8 0,0 63.9,0 237.5,0"/>
        </svg>
        <div id="blip">
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
                <a href="#" id="blog">Blog</a>
                <a href="#" id="projects">Projects</a>
                <a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <button id="goback">Back</button>
        </div>
        <script src="anime.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var revealbtn = document.getElementById('showdashboard');
            var backbtn = document.getElementById('goback');
            
            revealbtn.onclick = function(){
                var morphing = anime({
                    targets: '.polymorph',
                    points: [
                        {value:'237.5,104.8 0,104.8 0,0 63.9,0 33.9,63.6'},
                        {value:'237.5,104.8 0,104.8 0,0 0,0 33.9,63.6'}
                    ],
                    easing: 'easeOutQuad',
                    duration: 800,
                    loop: false
                });
                
                anime({
                    targets: '#blip',
                    opacity: 1,
                    duration: 1000,
                    translateY: 250
                })
                
                var promise = morphing.finished.then(()=>{
                    backbtn.onclick = function(){
                        var morphing = anime({
                            targets: '.polymorph',
                            points:[
                                {value:'237.5,104.8 0,104.8 0,0 63.9,0 33.9,63.6'},
                                {value:'237.5,104.8 0,104.8 0,0 63.9,0 237.5,0'},
                            ],
                            easing: 'easeOutQuad',
                            duration: 800,
                            loop: false
                        });
                        
                        anime({
                            targets:'#blip',
                            opacity: 0,
                            duration: 1000,
                            translateY: -800
                        })
                    };
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work by changing the css slightly. Please have a look at the following [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GATEU3ELEB8G)

Changed CSS

```css
#mySidenav a {
  position: fixed;
  right: -80px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  right: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

I've set the color to transparent so it's hidden if not hovered and also changed the position from `left` to `right`.
Next change the hover state color to white to display the text.

**Update**

I've changed the border radius so it's on the left egde of the items. Also position changed to `fixed` to remove the scrollbar and to have the menu always on that position (even with a vertical scrollbar).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works, however, the thing is now it has a scroll bar so if I scroll all the way to the left you can see the navigation bar. Thank you so much though

Comment: You're welcome. For the scrollbar issue, you can add `overflow: hidden` to the body. Or better, change `#mySidenave a` position to `fixed`. This will ensue that the navbar is always at that position and there will be no scrollbar.

Comment: Changed the `#blip` to `fixed`. Thank you so very very very much!

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as changing your css. In your html code, you have the navigation bar wrapped inside of a div with the name of "blip". This means that when you set the following:

```
    #blip{
      position: absolute;
      right: 25%;
    }
```

You are making it so that the entire div is 25% of the entire width of the page FROM the right-hand side. Simply set the value of 'right' to 0 and you should have what you want!